# How to use 'NeedsTeXFormat{}' Option

Tags: latex, tex

So I am trying to understand how `\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}` is actually used. All the documentation I can find basically says to add a date after the `\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}` with `[]` however, I cannot figure out if there is any other option for `\NeedsTeXFormat{}` for using the newer `LaTeX3` items.

I am trying to teach myself how to write a class by updating my university's thesis class since it is about 8 years out of date and is using some packages that are deprecated and broken.

Comment: Can you give an example of what new l3 item you need?

Comment: No as I am just trying to understand what this command actually does. Like it seems like it locks the class into using only the `LaTeX 2e` format. There's zero documentation that i can find on this command.  As for the `l3` layer, I haven't gotten that far yet. I am first working on moving it away from `tabu` package

Comment: It is documented in https://texdoc.org/serve/source2e/0 , page 807 .

Comment: :thumbsup: for moving away from tabu!!! Good decision!

Comment: Even with l3 programming commands, you still want the 2e format. Just make sure that the version is new enough to support the commands you want to use. Such a test is for example done here: new commands if format is new enough, the older commands as fall back for older formats https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/blob/f748f31c41c56ef0574131feacf1c2e24778ff5e/base/beamerbasecompatibility.sty#L54

Comment: (if you have any specific questions about l3, you can find most of its authors in this chat https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41 )